# How to build ICMPv6 packet with libnet?

Tags: ipv6, icmp, libnet

Is it possible to build ICMPv6 packet with libnet? The only functions I see are concerning ICMPv4 ( libnet_build_icmpv4_xxxxx() ). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone who might look for the solution: Sorry, no, I found out it was not possible. You have to build ICMPv6 manually :(